# python postgres change values of rows while reading results

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-10

I am using python3, postgress 10  and Psycopg2 to query multiple records like so

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(<my connection string>)
with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:        
        cur.execute('select id,field1 from table1')
        for id, field1 from cur.fetchall():
           print(id,field1)
           #todo: how up update field1 to be f(field1) where f is an arbitrary python function
```

My question is: how do i update the value of the rows that I am reading and set the value of field1 to some arbitrary python-based calculation

edit: the purpose is to update the rows in the table

Comment: Do you want to update rows in the table?

Comment: @klin, yes - just updated the question

Comment: Have you tried opening another connection and running the update statements through that?

Answer (score 3):

You need another cursor, e.g.:

```
with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:        
        cur.execute('select id,field1 from table1')
        for id, field1 in cur.fetchall():
            print(id,field1)
            with conn.cursor() as cur_update:
                cur_update.execute('update table1 set field1 = %s where id = %s', (f(field1), id))
```

Note however that this involves as many updates as selected rows, which is obviously not efficient. The update can be done in a single query using  [psycopg2.extras.execute_values():](http://psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values)

```
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values
    
with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:        
        cur.execute('select id,field1 from table1')
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for id, field1 in rows:
            print(id,field1)
                
    # convert rows to new values of field1
    values = [(id, f(field1)) for id, field1 in rows]
    sql = '''
        with upd (id, field1) as (values %s)
        update table1 t
        set field1 = upd.field1
        from upd
        where upd.id = t.id
        '''
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        execute_values(cur, sql, values)
```